# multiple query parameters not being parsed

Tags: node.js, coap

I have the following code

```
    const coap = require('coap');
    const url = require('url');

    const server = coap.createServer((req, res) => {
        const uri = req.url; // Get the requested URI
        const path = uri.split('?')[0]; // Extract path from the URI

        if (path === '/variable') {
            handleVariable(req, res);
        } else if (path === '/update') {
            handleUpdate(req, res);
        } else if (path === '/observe') {
            handleObserve(req, res);
        } else if (path === '/test') {
            handleTest(req, res);
        } else {
            // Handle other URIs if needed
            console.log(`${uri} not found`);
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end('Not Found');
        }
    });

    // Start the CoAP server on port 5683 (default CoAP port)
    server.listen(() => {
        console.log('CoAP server started on port 5683');
    });

    function handleTest(req, res) {
        if (req.method == 'GET') {

            const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
            const id = parsedUrl.query.id;

            console.log(req);
            console.log(req.url);
            console.log(id);
            // Respond with the current value of the variable
            res.write("Test suttessful");
            res.end();

        }
    }
```

and I am using `coap-client` to send requests to the server. The problem I am facing is when I send multiple query parameters.

this is my command

```
 coap-client -m get coap://127.0.0.1:5683/variable?uid=one&did=2
```

for some reason when I print the URL I receive, it only includes the first query parameter and not the second

I end up receiving only
`/variable?uid=one` and nothing after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the `coap-client` command from a shell, presumably a UNIX shell.

The '&' character is interpreted by the shell to run the previous command in the background, so what your client program is really doing is

```bash
coap-client -m get coap://127.0.0.1:5683/variable?uid=one &
did=2
```

(did=2 is an assignment and thus doesn't cause an error; sending the coap-client program to the background is barely noticeable because it returns fast.

If you protect the URI from the shell's processing by quoting it, you should get the right results:

```
coap-client -m get "coap://127.0.0.1:5683/variable?uid=one&did=2"
```

(Related notes: You don't need to specify port 5683 because it is the default port. When you use IPv6 addresses such as `coap-client -m get "coap://[::1]/variable"`, the quotes will also prevent shell processing of the brackets.)